# Python - Download files from https

Tags: python, download, beautifulsoup

I am using Python with BeautifoulSoup. Hereby I am also downloading filtered files from the web (https). Here the part of my code how I download the files.
Totally I get over 480 files. 450 files are getting downloaded correctly, but the rest there is no content in the file. It only contains Error 404 or the file is completely damaged and cannot be opened.

```
if filename().endswith('Doc'):
   print(filename)
   file = open('C:/RC/' + filename, 'wb')
   file.write(one_file.content)
        file.close()
else:
   filename.append(one_file.text.strip())
```

Would you have an idea what could lead to an error for the rest of the files?

Comment: Have you tried going to those urls to see if the file is actually there? 404 errors are generally because the URL itself is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the files are existing if I do open them manually and there are contents in the files. 
I get the files from a kind git repository. As Lawrence described, there could be some refusals after a specific multiple requests, a delay needs be be implemented maybe.ö

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that some of your requests are failing. Thus, the answer lies in the other parts of your code, namely the one that is making the requests. The first thing to do would be to verify the response code, and implement the retry functionality on code 404. The next thing to do would be to add a delay in between requests, because it may be the server is refusing too many requests in the short amount of time. Yet another thing could be that your User-Agent is not properly setup and you are being refused on some domains (assuming you are downloading files from multiple domains). These are just a few possible reasons, but there might be others.

Comment: Thanks for the info Lawrence. Could it be also due to login session expiration? Do you know how long can be a login session stay?

Comment: The common practice is for the login session to never expire if there are frequent-enough requests sent. Basically, the default setup for most servers is that the session expires after 20 minutes of inactivity. Since you are being active with sending bunch of requests, I wouldn't worry about session expiration.